# Extracting links from a URL until there is data and then moving to the next URL

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have a URL from where I am trying to extract data. I have found a way to extract data from that url. but how do i then move to the next URL if the existing URL doesn't have any data?

The base URL  have used in main function is,
https://posoco.in/reports/daily-reports/

instead I only want to extract data from 2020-21 and then go on from here,
https://posoco.in/reports/daily-reports/daily-reports-2020-21/

this way if the pdf files from 2020-21 is all extracted, then the program should start extracting from the next URL which is 2021-22 so on as long as the website exists in an automated way so program can check them automated every-year.

The code I have written.

```
#import libraries
import re
import tabula
import datetime
from datetime import datetime,timedelta
from datetime import timedelta, date
import requests
import pandas as pd
import glob
import logging
import os
import urllib.request
import urllib.error
import urllib.parse
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import wget

def source_urls(url):
    html = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    tags = soup('a')
    filelink = []
    for link in tags:
        if ('daily-reports-' in link.get('href','')):
            filelink.append(link.get('href'))
    return filelink

def get_urls(url):
    html = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    tags = soup('a')
    filelink = []
    for link in tags:
        if ('_nldc_psp/?wpdmdl' in link.get('href','')):
            filelink.append(link.get('href'))
    return filelink

if __name__ == "__main__":
    url = 'https://posoco.in/reports/daily-reports/'
    file_links = source_urls(url)
    sorted_file_links = sorted(file_links)
    for files in sorted_file_links:
        sub_files = get_urls(files)
        for x in sub_files:
            print(x)
```

The program output

```
https://posoco.in/download/31.03.14_nldc_psp/?wpdmdl=3256
https://posoco.in/download/30.03.14_nldc_psp/?wpdmdl=3255
https://posoco.in/download/29.03.14_nldc_psp/?wpdmdl=3254
https://posoco.in/download/28.03.14_nldc_psp/?wpdmdl=3253
....
...
...
...
...
https://posoco.in/download/11-03-21_nldc_psp/?wpdmdl=35681
https://posoco.in/download/10-03-21_nldc_psp/?wpdmdl=35649
https://posoco.in/download/09-03-21_nldc_psp/?wpdmdl=35627
https://posoco.in/download/08-03-21_nldc_psp/?wpdmdl=35612
https://posoco.in/download/07-03-21_nldc_psp/?wpdmdl=35589
```

I have pasted all the libraries, but only a few are used here. rest are used to download and for processing and logging.

Comment: So basically what you're asking is how to set up a cron job that runs your script every year? Your code works just fine (although it could be significantly refactored). To get new urls you need to wait till 2022. Having said all that, *what's your problem?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you've to set an condition where it's will pickup the main `urls` which is equal/bigger than `2021-20`

And then you can parse the inner `urls`.

Also, There's no need to use `.get` here!

Since you are using a condition to pickup urls include `_nldc_psp/?wpdmdl`which means if there's a pattern then return it. so you **DONNOT** need to replace the value with empty values `link.get('href','')` and then return it!

```
import httpx
import trio
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from datetime import datetime
from pprint import pprint as pp

cond = datetime.strptime('2020-21', '%Y-%d')


async def get_urls(client):
    r = await client.get('https://posoco.in/reports/daily-reports/')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
    return [x['href'] for x in soup.select('a[href*=reports-]') if datetime.strptime(x['href'].split('-', 3)[-1][:-1], '%Y-%d') >= cond]


async def main():
    async with httpx.AsyncClient(timeout=None) as client, trio.open_nursery() as nurse:
        links = await get_urls(client)

        async def get_pdf(url):
            r = await client.get(url)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
            pp([x['href']
                for x in soup.select('a[href*="nldc_psp"]')])

        if links:
            for link in links:
                nurse.start_soon(get_pdf, link)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    trio.run(main)
```